# Parsing Game Entities

Tags: c#, design-patterns, parsing

Could use some help with my presentation in Software Development. I'm presenting how I reworked a game's parser ([SpaceTaxi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cEcxgPvmQqU)). Basically we take in a .txt file with ASCII characters and convert them into entities that can be rendered in our game.

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qNUX.png), [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKk5w.jpg)

In between the input and output I've written a parser. I've tried to follow the *Facade Design Pattern* with the *SOLID principles* in mind.

I'm not sure how much code I should show here as I don't want to flood you, so I am going to upload some of it but tell me if it's sufficient.

**What my code is intended to do**

The parser should be a single instance and when called (`Parser.StartParse(string txtFile)`) the parser should go through a txt file comparing ascii characters with image files.
The image files are given to our project.

**IParse.cs**

```
public interface IParse {
    void Parse(string[] txtFile);
    void Add(List<char> map);
}

public class ParseObstacles : IParse {

        public Dictionary<char, string> Dict;
        public List<Entity> Entities;

        public ParseObstacles() {
            Dict = new Dictionary<char, string>();
            Entities = new List<Entity>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Extracts the txt information about what each character represents.
        ///     Example from the-beach.txt: "A) aspargus-edge-left.png"
        ///     Here we split ')' to first get the character, A, and it's
        ///     correspondent filename, 'aspargus-edge-left.png'.
        /// </summary>
        public void Parse(string[] txtFile) {
            foreach (var i in txtFile) {
                if (i.Contains(")")) {
                    var tile = i.Split(')')[0].ToCharArray()[0];
                    var name = i.Split(')')[1].Trim();
                    Dict.Add(tile, name);
                }
            }
        }

        public void Add(List<char> map) {
            ParseHelper.AddEntities(map, Dict, Entities);
        }
    }
```

I intended for the parser to follow the facade pattern.
Does this code in fact implement the facade pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we encounter interface `IParse`.

> ```
> public interface IParse {
>     void Parse(string[] txtFile);
>     void Add(List<char> map);
> }
> ```

You should use C# conventions.

- interface name should be a noun or noun phrase `IParse` -> `IParser`
- use a plural name for a variable that represents a sequence of items `txtFile` -> `segments??`
- use a meaningful name to describe structures `map` -> `??` -> doesn't say anything
- use the correct types, preferrably interfaces, when dealing with sequences; For instance, `IEnumerable` to iterate, `IList` to manipulate.
- Note that your interface does not have any state or return values. We are never able to interact with it bi-directionally. Too much encapsulation perhaps?

Refactored:

```
public interface IParser {
    void Parse(IEnumerable<string> segments); // or whatever we are talking about ?
    void Add(IList<char> map); // what is map ?
}
```

Let's move on to `ParseObstacles`.

Your state is public, is this as designed or a code smell? Again, use conventions.

> ```
> public Dictionary<char, string> Dict;
> public List<Entity> Entities;
> ```

```
private IDictionary<char, string> values; // they are values I suppose
private IList<Entity> entities;
```

Next, we find method *Parse*.

- the signature is already changed by interface implementation
- Only use `i` as an index in an iterator
- perform `i.Split(')')` once
- `Dict` is already renamed previously

> ```
> public void Parse(string[] txtFile) {
>     foreach (var i in txtFile) {
>         if (i.Contains(")")) {
>             var tile = i.Split(')')[0].ToCharArray()[0];
>             var name = i.Split(')')[1].Trim();
>             Dict.Add(tile, name);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

After changing the method:

```
 public void Parse(IEnumerable<string> segments) {
      foreach (var segment in segments) {
          if (segment.Contains(")")) {
              var tokens = segment.Split(')');
              var tile = tokens[0].ToCharArray()[0];
              var name = tokens[1].Trim();
              values.Add(tile, name);
          }
      }
 }
```

Next up, method `Add`. This is a black-box for us. Consider the fact `ParseHelper` adds cyclomatic complexity to your API. Perhaps its code should be divided into the other classes.

> ```
> public void Add(List<char> map) {
>      ParseHelper.AddEntities(map, Dict, Entities);
> }
> ```

```
public void Add(IList<char> map) {
       // not convinced about ParseHelper ..
       ParseHelper.AddEntities(map, values, entities);
}
```

And finally, `ParserFacade`.

Let's have a look at the singleton.

- A private constructor, well done.
- A nested static class holding the singleton, [good design](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton).
- all caps -> take it easy: `INSTANCE` -> `Instance`
- a getter method is best substituted with a property getter: `getInstance()` -> `Instance`

> ```
> private ParserFacade() { }
>
> private static class ParserFacadeHolder {
>     public static readonly ParserFacade INSTANCE = new ParserFacade();
> }
>
> public static ParserFacade getInstance() {
>     return ParserFacadeHolder.INSTANCE;
> }
> ```

After changes:

```
private static class ParserFacadeHolder {
    public static readonly ParserFacade Instance = new ParserFacade();
}

public static ParserFacade Instance => ParserFacadeHolder.Instance;
```

I don't like this helper class, but I did expect it to be static. Here you used an instance.

> `private ParseHelper parseHelper;`

Public state detected. Code smell?

> ```
>  public ParseExits exits;
>  public ParseObstacles obstacles;
>  public ParsePlatforms platforms;
>  public ParseCustomers customers;
> ```

Method `StartParse`:

What bothers me here is the inconsistent and convoluted design of parsing behavior. `ParseExits` (and sibling classes) can parse the file. But then the facade calls the infamous helper to parse additional data, to then forward this data to `ParseExits`. This design is too complex in behavioral complexity.

> ```
>  exits = new ParseExits();
>  exits.Parse(file);
>  exits.Add(ParseHelper.GetAllTiles(file));
> ```

Comment: The thing is about ParseHelper.cs I have some code which all the sibling classes uses. So was not sure if it was a good idea to add some sort of class which could hold these methods they all use. Wanted to avoid copy+pasting

Comment: @user10829235 There is a bit of everything in that class :-)

Comment: Code smell I guess. Damn.

I thought a lot about the public/private scenario. I wanted my GameLoop in another file to be able to call Parser.exit.Entities or Parser.exit.Dict so I left it public purposely. But thank you for being aware of the small details. This is what really helps me